# jquery tablesorter and filesizes

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, filesize

I'm currently trying to implement jquery tablesorter and one of my columns is filesizes, I've found a snippet of code for this, however I keep getting errors.

If anyone could help me out that'd be great.

**jQuery TableSorter:** http://tablesorter.com/

**jQuery TableSorter Filesize code:** http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/fd5729a7175f6710?fwc=1

**My Table:**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox header"><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxAll" name="checkboxAll"></th>
      <th valign="middle" align="left" class="header filename"><strong>Filename</strong></th>
      <th valign="middle" align="left" class="header filesize"><strong>Size</strong></th>
      <th valign="middle" align="left" class="header filedate"><strong>Date</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="file">
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" name="checkbox[]"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">002.jpg</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">113 kb</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">21/10/2010 12:18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" name="checkbox[]"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">kasper.jpg</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">41 kb</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">05/07/2010 11:33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" name="checkbox[]"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">Linda__Angela.jpg</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">212 kb</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">05/07/2010 11:46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" name="checkbox[]"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">loader.gif</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">5 kb</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">05/07/2010 11:33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" name="checkbox[]"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">Lucas.jpg</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">111 kb</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">05/07/2010 11:46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" name="checkbox[]"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">people.psd</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">2 mb</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">05/07/2010 11:33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" name="checkbox[]"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">people1.jpg</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">16 kb</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">05/07/2010 11:33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" name="checkbox[]"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">P_750g_Basmati_FCollection.zip</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">265 mb</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">05/07/2010 11:46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" name="checkbox[]"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">T_2kg_LongWhite_FCollection.zip</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">441 mb</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">05/07/2010 11:50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**My jQuery code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

          jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: 'filesize', 
            is: function(s) { 
             return s.match(new RegExp( /[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\ (KB|B|GB|MB|TB)/ ));
            }, 
            format: function(s) {
              var suf = s.match(new RegExp( /(KB|B|GB|MB|TB)$/ ))[1];
              var num = parseFloat(s.match( new RegExp( /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/ ))[0]);
              switch(suf) {
                case 'B':
                  return num;
                case 'KB':
                  return num * 1024;
                case 'MB':
                  return num * 1024 * 1024;
                case 'GB':
                  return num * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
                case 'TB':
                  return num * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
                }
            }, 
            type: 'numeric' 
          }); 

          jQuery(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
            headers: {
              2: { sorter: 'filesize' }
            }                                
          });
        });
```

**The error:**

s.match(new RegExp(/(KB|B|GB|MB|TB)$/)) is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the regexp is case sensitive. The regexp contains B, KB, MB etc, but your values are b, kB, mB, etc.

Add an "i" after a Regexp to make it case insensitive. Like this:

```
new RegExp(/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\ (KB|B|GB|MB|TB)/i)

new RegExp(/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the regex should look like this?

```
 s.match(new RegExp(/.*(KB|B|GB|MB|TB)$/))
```

Since you want to ignore the number part there...